# Is 食品昏睡状態 a thing?

Tags: translation

I have effectively zero knowledge of Japanese, but I'm trying to learn :D Out of curiosity I tried to see if something like the german "Fresskoma" (english: food coma?), i.e., the lethargic state after eating too much food, exists in Japanese. I came up with 食品昏睡 (probably ridiculous :D), but then I found [this](http://ja.termwiki.com/JA/food_coma), which suggests that 食品昏睡状態 actually exists. Is that an actual thing? :)

Comment: The page you linked is a machine-translated article. The content is so broken that I can't even imagine the original English explanation :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

食品昏睡（状態） is not a word and doesn't really make sense...

> "Fresskoma" (english: food coma?), i.e., the lethargic state after eating too much food

Literal translations would not work here... I think you could translate it as 「[食後]{しょくご}の[眠気]{ねむけ}」「食後の[睡魔]{すいま}」「[満腹時]{まんぷくじ}の眠気」 etc., or explain it as 「[食事]{しょくじ}のあと[眠]{ねむ}くなること」「[食]{た}べたあと眠くなること」「[満腹]{まんぷく}になると眠くなること」 etc.